# How can I set extra, custom arguments for androiddeployqt via CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: android, qt, cmake, qt6

Is it possible to append an argument to the `androiddeployqt` call via CMakeLists.txt (Qt 6.4+)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I think the answer is currently no. At the time of this writing, the latest version of [the `Android/Androiddeployqt.cmake` file](https://github.com/Tereius/cmake-QtDeployHelper/blob/fac951fb41113dbbb8e8974b37232a8fa7c3c17a/Android/Androiddeployqt.cmake#L433) works like this:

> ```
>     # create a custom command that will run the androiddeployqt utility to generate the APK
>     add_custom_target(
>         apk
>         DEPENDS ${ARG_TARGET}
>         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI} # it seems that recompiled libraries are not copied if we don't remove them first
>         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}
>         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:${ARG_TARGET}> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}
>         COMMAND ${ANDROID_DEPLOY_QT} $<$<BOOL:${CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE}>:--verbose> --output ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} --input ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtdeploy.json $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:--no-strip> $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:--no-strip> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:--release> $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:--release> $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:--release> --no-generated-assets-cache --jdk ${JAVA_HOME_DIR} --gradle ${TARGET_LEVEL_OPTIONS} ${SIGN_OPTIONS}
>     )
>     
>     # create a custom command that will install the APK on a connected android device
>     add_custom_target(
>         apk-install
>         DEPENDS apk
>         COMMAND ${ANDROID_DEPLOY_QT} $<$<BOOL:${CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE}>:--verbose> --no-build --reinstall --output ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} --input ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtdeploy.json $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:--no-strip> $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:--no-strip> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:--release> $<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:--release> $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:--release> --no-generated-assets-cache --jdk ${JAVA_HOME_DIR} --gradle ${TARGET_LEVEL_OPTIONS} ${SIGN_OPTIONS}
>     )
> ```

I don't see any points for adding extra things. `SIGN_OPTIONS` does not look to be a free configuration point. You can [create an issue ticket](https://github.com/Tereius/cmake-QtDeployHelper/issues) requesting such functionality and explaining why it would be useful. The only other option you have if you don't want to do that, or need to make such changes urgently, is to patch the `Android/Androiddeployqt.cmake` yourself.

Comment: I wanted to test new in Qt 6.3 "--copy-dependencies-only" argument

Comment: @morte As far as I know, you only have two choices: contact the upstream maintainer of this CMake script and ask for changes that would support what you want to do, or patch the this CMake script yourself on your local machine.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

Comment: Related issue https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86056 (do not deploy unused style plugins). There is also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-114588 (discussion about possibility of replacement androiddeployqt with CMake).